# A spam bot loves me, what can I do?

Tags: spam, akismet

I'm receiving many many spam comments using the same username and I guess it is a bot that keeps on submitting comments. In one week I get around 100 such comments (which is quite a lot for my small blog). I want to have a look at all comments that are marked as spam (just in case Akismet is too strict on a certain legit comment), but this is really annoying. Therefore I have two small questions:

- How can I tell WP to trash all comments that come from a certain username?
- What do you generally do in situations like this?

Comment: It is not at all helpful to downvote without explanation!

Comment: +1 - I found this question by searching here for "blacklist" and the answers here helped me. You raised a good question, agree, one should comment when downvoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually want to keep these comments marked as spam--not trashed. Akismet checks against your spam list while deciding what to do with a new comment. So having a large database of spam comments actually helps Akismet work.

I get what your issue is, but what you're essentially asking for is a spam filter for your spam filter.

If you're having trouble with a particular user, you might consider disabling their account somehow. This is pretty easily done by changing their username and password in the DB to something unguessable. This ensures that they can't sign in, and can't create another account using the same email address.

Comment: +1 on "spam filter for spam filter". WordPress dilutes this too much by having spam, trash, Akismet queue and whatever other plugins chip in. Too many piles to decide between efficiently.

Comment: This makes some sense. So, you are saying that I should leave spam comments there in the spam box and not trashing them? Then, do you ever look at the spam queue?

Comment: You can check the spam queue for false positives. But you don't want to move all the spam comments to trash--leave them marked as spam.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? AFAIK there's no benefit to keeping comments already marked as spam; Akismet remembers your decisions.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I tell WP to trash all comments that come from a certain username?

*Settings > Discussion > Comment Blacklist* - any words there will auto-spam comment, it matches against name and other comment's fields.

> What do you generally do in situations like this?

I use my own spam filter that I am confident is extremely unlikely to produce false positives.

Akismet is mainstream thanks to bundling, but really efficient spam filtering is picking tools relevant to amount and types of spam that specific blog gets.

Comment: Firstly those comments are already marked as spam, I want to make them go to trash automatically. Secondly most of the spam I get on different (small) blogs that I manage is porn. I believe this is common to all blogs thus cannot understand your point about "picking tools".

Comment: @phunehehe sorry on spam/trash, I misread the question. Commonality of spam is oversimplification. There are different methods (bots, humans), goals (SEO, malware, affiliates) and triggers (keywords and other factors that are attractive to spammers) that define spam. As for me generalization of spam is prime reason that large centralized service like Akismet is bound to be plagued with false positives and such.